# Does good electrical conductivity imply good thermal conductivity?

Tags: thermal-conduction, electrical

Typically materials which are good conductor of electricity are also good conductor of heat, and vice versa. Are there notable exceptions?

Comment: the free electrons that can travel between atoms also serve to spread thermal energy. ... https://www.doitpoms.ac.uk/tlplib/thermal_electrical/images/weidemann_graph.png  ........ http://www.tibtech.com/images/conductivite_materiaux.JPG  ........... https://www.google.fr/search?q=diamond+thermal+versus+electrical+conductivity+metals&num=100&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiturnfrPDTAhXHOhoKHZnSBEoQ_AUICigB&biw=1004&bih=620#imgrc=CVaXcQoZqmU_WM:

Answer (score 11):

[Beryllium oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beryllium_oxide) is a very good electrical insulator but at the same time the best non-metal (except diamond) thermal conductor.

So to summarize. In general, good thermal conductivity is correlated with good electrical conductivity, but it is not a strict relationship.

For example, there is the empirical [Wiedemann-Franz law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiedemann%E2%80%93Franz_law) for metals which states that the ratio of thermal conductivity $k$ and electrical conductivity $\sigma$ is proportional to temperature $T$.

$$ \frac{k}{\sigma} =c_0T $$

The proportionality constant is $c_0$. But as the wiki article points out there are exceptions to this empirical relationship.

Answer (score 7):

For metals, good electrical conductivity does indeed imply good thermal conductivity. This is known from the Wiedemann–Franz law, which gives the ratio between electronic contribution of thermal conductivity ($\lambda$) and electrical conductivity ($\sigma$) and is proportional to the temperature ($T$).

$$\frac{\lambda}{\sigma} = LT $$

This gives the empirical constant $L$ known as the Lorenz number.

$$ L = \frac{\lambda}{\sigma T} = \frac{\pi^2}{3}(\frac{\lambda_B}{e})^2 = 2.44 \times 10^{-8} W\Omega K^{-2} $$

As stated, this law applies to metals. Diamond, for example, is an excellent thermal conductor because of its structure, but at the same time it has a very high resistance to electrical current.

Comment: And, naturally, it gets a little more interesting when playing with semimetals :-) .  By which I just mean complicated.  Electrons are pretty good at carrying energy.

Answer (score 2):

As alluded to in the other answers, a most notable exception is diamond. Diamond is an [excellent thermal conductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_properties_of_diamond). The thermal conductivity of natural diamond is around 22 W/(cm·K), which makes diamond five times better than copper at conducting heat. At the same time, the electrical resistivity of most diamonds is on the order of 10E11 to 10E18 Ω·m.